# I have a windows 10 PC that will start up, but will not let me log in and will not boot to safe mode, how can I re-install win10 and keep my files?

Tags: windows, windows-10, safe-mode

I have an ASUS laptop with some important personal files on it. It will boot to the Windows 10 login screen and will let me log in. However once I'm logged in the system just grinds to a halt and I can't open anything.

I would like to re-install windows yet keep personal files. I believe this is known in Windows 10 as "Reset my PC." I cannot get to settings (since the PC hangs on login) so I attempted to boot to safe mode with holding down 'shift' and selecting re-boot from the login menu. When I do this, I get a dialog box that pops up with title "bootim.exe - system error". Here's a picture of it

[image: bootim.exe error]

with an error. I click OK and the system proceeds to reboot, but not to safe mode.

So what are my options here? Last gasp is, of course take the HDD out into a 2.5" enclosure, save the files and do a clean install, but I was hoping to avoid that if there was a way to run 'reset this pc' from boot media. Unfortunately (I know, shame on me) I didn't create a restore point for windows in this case.

Comment: *So what are my options here?* I'd recommend you to boot from bootable flash or CD and make a copy of your files. Then do everything you want...

Comment: Please give the entire bootim error message.

Comment: hi @harrymc a link to an image of the error message has been added

Answer (score -1):

*Reset your PC* is not what you want, since it will erase all your own data.

Since you cannot boot from disk, the first step is to create a USB bootable media
on another functioning Windows 10 computer.

See the article
[How to Create Bootable USB Flash Drive to Install Windows 10 from](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2376-create-bootable-usb-flash-drive-install-windows-10-a.html).

Since the error mentions a boot component, try to do Startup Repair:

1. Boot from the USB and choose "Repair your computer"
2. Under *Advanced troubleshooting*, choose *Startup Repair*
3. Click on it and follow the instructions.

For more details on the above, see the article
[How to Boot or Repair Windows 10 using the Installation Media](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/boot-or-repair-windows-10-using-the-installation-media).

If this does not help, boot from the USB into Command and save your data,
then reinstall Windows. Hopefully the installation will detect Windows on the
disk and will "upgrade" it to itself, thus conserving most of your setup.

Comment: If you boot from USB it will not "detect Windows on the disk and will 'upgrade' it to itself".  If you boot from USB it will always do a clean install.

Comment: @lx07: If it detects the existing Windows setup, it may propagate some stuff from the existing installation.